# Cannot increase beacon scanning period - Altbeacon library

Tags: android, background, foreground, scanning, altbeacon

When I start the application, scanning starts and onBeaconServiceConnect() function triggered in 2-3 seconds. I need to increase it. Also I use background beacon scanning another class. And I use another beaconManager object.Though I use setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod() function to do this, it is not working. onBeaconServiceConnect() function is griggered in 2-3 seconds. How can I solve it ? My functions like as below:

------------------------ My main class to detect beacons on foreground----------------------

```
private void generateBeaconOptions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location acces");
            builder.setMessage("Please grat location acces so this app can detect beacons");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", null, null, null);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    if(!ConfigFile.isDemo()) {
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    UniPromClient.setIsInAnyBeaconRegion(true);
                    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                        logToDisplay("Detected " + beacon.toString() + " with UUID " + beacon.getId1().toString() + " and Major ID " + beacon.getId2().toString() + " and Minor ID " + beacon.getId3().toString());
                        UniPromClient.setUniPromBeacon(new UniPromBeacon(beacon.getId1().toString(),
                                beacon.getId2().toString(),
                                beacon.getId3().toString()));
                        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateUserScoreAsUserStaying();
                            }
                        });

                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    UniPromClient.setIsInAnyBeaconRegion(false);
                    UniPromClient.setUniPromBeacon(null);
                    logToDisplay("No iBeacons detected");
                }

                if (UniPromClient.isPrevIsAnyBeaconInRegion() != UniPromClient.isInAnyBeaconRegion()) {
                    if (UniPromClient.isInAnyBeaconRegion()) {
                        showMainActivityAlert("Uni Promotion alanına girdiniz :)");
                    } else if (!UniPromClient.isInAnyBeaconRegion() && UniPromClient.isPrevIsAnyBeaconInRegion()) {
                        showMainActivityAlert("Uni Promotion alanından çıktınız :(");
                    }
                    UniPromClient.setPrevIsAnyBeaconInRegion(UniPromClient.isInAnyBeaconRegion());
                    generateDrawerList();
                }
            }

        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

--------------------------My Backgorund class to detect beacons on background------------

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    //BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);
    //beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000l);
    Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    //backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
}
```

Comment: Binding to a service in Android should return almost instantaneously, so something is wrong.  What types of classes are the two shown above?  Activity?  Application? When are they called in sequence to each other?

Answer (score 1):

If scanning is already started when you change the scan periods, you must call `beaconManager.updateScanPeriods()` to have the changes take effect.

Also, note tgat to have foreground/background scan periods switch automatically, you must use the `BackgroundPowerSaver` which is shown as commented out.  If enabled, it will watch for activities being paused and resumed and set the scan rates to background settings when no Activities are visible.

If you do not want to use the `BackgroundPowerSaver`, you must call `beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);` to activate background scan rates.